# Is there a way to manipulate wordpress post styles loaded into an external iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am making a widget in which I need to show recent posts and the blogs archive from a WordPress site. I can get the feeds to the widget by loading the contents into an iframe. But I don't need the header and footer of the wordpress pages to be shown in the widget.

I used some couple of plugins to make a dummy page with no header and footer and that works for the blogs archive. But for the individual posts page, the plugin wont let me take the header and footer out.

I have encountered cross origin problem when trying to access the content within the iframe from the widget.

Is there another way I can do it within the widget? Or is there any way to do this inside wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by checking whether the page (WordPress) is loaded into an iframe and if so, do certain style changes. I did this inside WordPress itself, so every time the page is loaded into the widget, it knows it is inside an iframe and thus changes the style.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if (top === self) {
    //do nothing
  } else { 
  jQuery( ".single-post header" ).css( "display", "none" );
  jQuery( ".single-post .related_wrap" ).css( "display", "none" );
  jQuery( ".single-post .comments_wrap" ).css( "display", "none" );
  jQuery( ".single-post footer" ).css( "display", "none" );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant access an iframe's DOM. What you are gonna do is fetching the external content (currently is loaded in an iframe) and manipulate it with a php library such as [PHPQuery](https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery) or [SimpleHtmlDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net). Based on my experience PHPQuery performs better than the others.